# Get error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError even when jar file has that method

Tags: java, exception

I got this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
     gnu.trove.TObjectIntHashMap.adjustOrPutValue(Ljava/lang/Object;II)I
```

I added trove4j-2.0.2.jar in my project. It's already contained `gnu.trove.TObjectIntHashMap.adjustOrPutValue` method.

What's wrong with this? Thanks.

Comment: Some code showing what you did to get this error would be helpful.

Comment: Don't you have multiple version of the trove4j atifact in your classpath? Can you list the project dependencies?

Comment: adjustOrPutValue(K key, int adjust_amount, int put_amount) but you provided only one or two paramters. Your first parameter is also an array or sth else, but not a simple object but it should be the key.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Olivier was right. I added multiple version of trove, that caused the problem. I fixed it. Thanks.